# Multilingual errors in codeigniter file upload class

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, error-handling, multilingual

When using the file upload class in codeigniter
display_errors() returns the errors in English language.

Is it somehow possible to define custom error messages or have the upload class pick from a different language file(currently it picks from the english language in the core files)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the upload class in system/libraries/upload.php 
You will need to change the set_error method to fetch the language you desire.

```
    public function set_error($msg, $log_level = 'error')
{

    //$this->_CI->lang->load('upload'
    $this->_CI->lang->load('upload','spanish');

    is_array($msg) OR $msg = array($msg);
    foreach ($msg as $val)
    {
        $msg = ($this->_CI->lang->line($val) === FALSE) ? $val : $this->_CI->lang->line($val);
        $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
        log_message($log_level, $msg);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Now you'll need to create your language file in system/language
and add the file upload_lang.php
You can get the original array structure from system/language/english/upload_lang.php

Answer (score 0):

A way without modifying system/core files would be to update the config setting:

Use it in your controller method or in your controller constructor:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'english');
```